# Is there a "lower_bound"-like method in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

In C++, `std::map#lower_bound` looks up the element and returns an iterator on it, or if it's not in the map, returns an iterator on the closest element in the map which is smaller.

Is there a method in Ruby with the same behavior like `std::map#lower_bound` for an instance of `Hash`? If not, should I extend the `Hash` class with my method, or is there a combination of functions to achieve the same effect/complexity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby Hashes do not have this ability because there is no way to find the closest element in a Hash to an element that does not exist in the Hash.  This is a property of all hashes, not just Ruby Hashes.  Two elements can be stored very far away from each other even if their values are very close--it all depends on the hash function that is being used.

The reason map.lower_bound is possible in C++ is because std::map is a tree, not a hash, and so tree lookup involves visiting all the (log n) layers of the tree (in the worst case) regardless of whether a key exists or not.  As Said says, use a rbtree (or some other balanced tree-like data structure, e.g. https://github.com/Kanwei/Algorithms/) if you require lower_bound-like behavior.

Answer (score 2):

There's a gem [rbtree](http://rbtree.rubyforge.org/).
It maps keys to values like a Hash, but maintains its elements in ascending key order. The interface is the almost identical to that of Hash.

```
gem install rbtree
```

**Example:**

```
require "rbtree"

rbtree = RBTree["a", 20, "b", 40, "c", 60, "d", 80, "e", 100]

itlow = rbtree.lower_bound("b")
itup = rbtree.upper_bound("d")

rbtree.bound(itlow.first, itup.first) do |k, v|
  puts "- #{[k, v]}"
end
```

**Output:**

```
-- ["b", 40]
-- ["c", 60]
-- ["d", 80]
```

Answer (score 1):

The suggestion about using a tree instead of hash is probably the best. But you can use the more brute force way to get these values, too.

```
  def get_lower_bound(hash, dt)
      lb_key = nil
      lb_val = nil
      hash.each do |key, val|
          if lb_key == nil or lb_key <= key and key <= dt
              lb_key = key
              lb_val = val
          end
      end
      lb_val
  end

  def get_upper_bound(hash, dt)
      ub_key = nil
      ub_val = nil
      hash.each do |key, val|
          if ub_key == nil or ub_key >= key and key >= dt
              ub_key = key
              ub_val = val
          end
      end
      ub_val
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use higher_entry/higher_key and lower_entry/lower_key for upper_bound and lower_bound using [treemap library](https://rubygems.org/gems/treemap/versions/1.0.3)

Treemap can be an effective performance driven solution.
Using keys like ceiling_entry, higher_entry and floor_entry can give the upper bound and lower bounds respectively. The keys ending with _entry here gives a constant time retrieval. On contrary functions for same ending with _key can give a logN solution.

https://github.com/davidkellis/treemap/blob/master/lib/treemap/tree_map.rb
https://github.com/davidkellis/treemap